# ¿Como separar una cadena de texto por medio de un espacio?

Tags: java

En mi codigo:
String nex = teclado.next().split('/n'); (Teclado es de tipo Scanner)
Como se puede identirfiacar el espacio en el .split() y el fin de la cadena.

Answer (score 0):

Se consigue de la siguiente manera:

```
    String nex = teclado.nextLine();  //se debe leer con nextLine no con next
    String separado[]=nex.split(" ");
```

**separado** es un arreglo el cual contiene lo que has leído seperado por espacios.

Comment: Lo mejor es usar `String#split("\\s+");`